# Viewmodel IEnumerable property is empty

Tags: object, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller, ienumerable

I'm in the middle of making an ASP .NET MVC4 based app. I'm a complete newb in that field. The idea is quite simple - have a some members in DB, show them listed, select desired ones via check boxes and redirect to some other controller which would do something with the previously selected members.

**Problem is passing the list of members from View to the Controller.** I've thought it would work with ViewModel. It certainly works from Controller to the View, but not the other way.

My ViewModel:

```
public class MembersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Directory_MVC.Models.Member> MembersEnum { get; set; }

    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Snippet of my Controller:

```
public class MembersController : Controller
{
    private MainDBContext db = new MainDBContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new Directory_MVC.ViewModels.MembersViewModel();

        // populating from DB
        model.MembersEnum = db.Members.Include(m => m.Group).Include(m => m.Mother).Include(m => m.Father);

        model.Test = "abc";

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GoToSendEmail(Directory_MVC.ViewModels.MembersViewModel returnedStruct)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // it is valid here
            return Redirect("http:\\google.com");
        }
    }
```

Snippet of my View:

```
@model Directory_MVC.ViewModels.MembersViewModel


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Members listing";

var lineCount = 0;
string lineStyle;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("GoToSendEmail", "Members", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model.MembersEnum)
{
    lineCount++;

    // set styling
    if (lineCount % 2 == 1)
    {
        lineStyle = "odd-line";
    }
    else
    {
        lineStyle = "even-line";
    }

    <tr class="@lineStyle">
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Selected)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mother.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mother.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Father.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Father.LastName)
        </td>
  <!-- other print-outs but not all properties of Member or Mother/father are printed -->
    </tr>
 }

</table>

<input type="submit" value="Send E-mail" />
}
```

The data are shown OK in the View. However, **when I submit that form the returnedStruct.MembersEnum and Test string are both null** in the Controller's method GoToSendEmail.

Is there a mistake or is there another possible way how to pass that members structure and check their Selected property?

Comment: you can not post list object to the ActionResult you may want to work on some alternate way like FormCollection

Comment: @HaBo - This is incorrect. You can bind to collections perfectly fine in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @David  just saw your answer, I didn't knew about this. Learned something. Will try this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model binding to a collection works a little differently. Each item has to have an identifier so that inputs don't all have the same name. I've answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648337/mvc-form-not-posting-table-date/12648773#12648773).

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MembersEnum.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.MembersEnum[i].FirstName)
}
```

...which should render something like...

```
<input type="text" name="MembersEnum[0].FirstName" value="" />
<input type="text" name="MembersEnum[1].FirstName" value="" />
<input type="text" name="MembersEnum[2].FirstName" value="" />
```

...which should then populate the collection in your ViewModel when picked up by the controller...

```
public ActionResult GoToSendEmail(ViewModels.MembersViewModel model)
```

As mentioned in the other answer, I'd have a look at some related articles from [Scott Hansleman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) and [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

You also mentioned that your string called `Test` is `null` when you submit to your `POST` action. You haven't added a field for this property anywhere within your form, so there's nothing for the model binder to bind to. If you add a field for it within your form then you should see the value in the `POST` action:

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Test)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's guided me to this blogpost [link](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). The described Html.BeginCollectionItem() helper is perfect for my needs. It works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Html.BeginCollectionItem() helper did the job - [BeginCollectionItem](http://nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/).